# How would I update my project to use the new backend which is ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, extjs, backend

My current project uses the Ext JS framework and I am not familiar with how to update it to use the new backend which is ASP.Net Core. Where do I start from here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Ext.NET (`https://ext.net/`) would help you out.

Combining the leading client and server-side web technologies, including Ext JS and ASP.NET, Ext.NET brings a rock-solid component framework for web application development. Focus on creating your critical business logic while Ext.NET handles the web components for your applications. Its unparalleled cross-browser compatibility and advanced MVC architecture empower devs to create structured and scalable enterprise-grade applications.